# Custom made control that inherits from Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl doesn't have access to SetPopupMenu

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a custom made control that inherits from `Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl`

I would like to assign a `TPopupMenu` instance to it but that doesn't work, because PopupMenu appears to be not accessible.

I'm not sure why that is ?  The online documentation seems to suggest PopupMenu is available in TCustomControl ?
However `__property TPopupMenu* PopupMenu = {read=FPopupMenu, write=SetPopupMenu};` is `protected`

I redefined the property as `public` in the custom made control
But now the error is that `SetPopupMenu` is not accessible. `SetPopupMenu` is not listed as `protected`.  Perhaps `private` ?  I'm not seeing it in the documentation.

Is this a virtual implementation and is it as simple as adding a `TPopupMenu` member and writing a `SetPopupMenu` function myself ?  What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PopupMenu` property is `protected` in `TControl` and not promoted in `TCustomControl`.  So you need to *promote* it to `public`/`__published` in your derived class, but do not *redeclare* it entirely, which it sounds like you are trying to do.

And yes, `SetPopupMenu()` is `private` (in `TControl`) and thus is not accessible to derived classes.

Try this:

```cpp
class TMyControl : public TCustomControl
{
    ...
__published:
    __property PopupMenu; // <-- that is all you need!
};
```

The same goes for any other `protected` base property that you want to expose access to in your derived control.